# showing an image until content is loaded

Tags: jquery

i am doing a jquery back end search of data from a DB table..until i fetch the data from the table...how do i show am image like every where its shown like searching or something like tht

---

I have a small doubt..My project has grown big. every where .change function is used. can i write a global code like when ever change function is called..show the image until the data is loaded???

Comment: If we know how you are doing your call, it will be easier to provide a suggestion.  Try posting the .ajax, .post, .get, or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more way is to use $.ajaxSetup to make show image on all of your queries:

```
$.ajaxSetup({   

beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
     $("#loading").show();
},

complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
 $("#loading").hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Have this image on your page initially...

```
<img id="loading" src="loading.gif" />
```

then with jQuery simply do this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

of if it's an ajax call (which I think it is) do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#loading").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: might be "safer" to use "complete" instead of "success"

Comment: you probably want to say $(function(){$("#loading").show()}); ?;)

Comment: Depends how you look at it I guess. I'm thinking it's already visible on the page but you could add the .show() before the .ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I just use code like

```
$(function(){
$('#id').change(function()
{
$.post('url.php',{name:$("#name").val()},function(data)
{
$("#html").html(data);
});
});
});
```

so i need to use the i`mge.show()`... juts before

`$("#html").html(data);`   rite ?

Comment: No, before $("#html").html(data); you probably want to hide image. And before ajax call - show it(or don't do anything if your image wasn't hidden before)

Comment: okie..you mean to say after 
$('#id').change(function()
{

i need to show the image and 
before 
$("#html").html(data);
i need to hide image.